# Парсинг сайта. Ошибка 500

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Пытаюсь получить данные с e-autopay.  Выгрузить свои заказы, т.к. толкового АПИ у этого сайта нет. 
Но не могу авторизоваться там. 
С помощью curl посылаю те же заголовки, однако что бы я не пробовал, посоянно выходит ошибка 500. 
Скажите, по каким еще параметрам система может не впускать меня к себе?

Отправляю токен, куки, referer, origin
Функция

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ref="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36";    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    $request = 'Origin:https://domen.e-autopay.com
Referer:https://domen.e-autopay.com/adminka/login/co-worker';
$split = explode("\n",$request);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$split ); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ref);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 400);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 ); 
    if($post)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login="mylogin"&password="mypassword"&_token="'.$token.'"');//токен забрал выше
  $curl=curl_exec($ch);

    $data = new simple_html_dom();
    $data->load($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch);
    var_dump($status);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
```

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь имитировать cURL'ом действия браузера, то, может, вам лучше браузер и взять? С Webdriver'ом (у него клиенты для целого ряда языков есть). И программно доставать нужную вам информацию.

Comment: берите в руки wireshark или аналоги и сравнивайте свои запросы и браузерные. Ищите разницу. Она может быть очень тонкая.